# Matlab read csv string array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, file-io, csv

I have a comma seperated dataset called Book2.csv I want to extract the contents. The contents are a 496024x1 array of strings  (normal, neptune, smurf).

I tryed:

```
 [text_data] = xlsread('Book2.csv');
```

But it just outputed a text_data empty array?

When trying csvread

```
M = csvread('Book2.csv')
??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 1) ==>
norma

Error in ==> csvread at 54
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c);
```

I get this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you try [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html)?

Comment: Give my [csvimport](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23573-csvimport) function a try :)

Comment: You should've provided file or at least part of it if you would like for someone to resolve the errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Off the top of my head this should get the job done.  But possibly not the best way to do it.

```
fid = fopen(your file);  //open file
 //read all contents into data as a char array 
 //(don't forget the `'` to make it a row rather than a column).
data = fread(fid, '*char')';
fclose(fid);
//This will return a cell array with the individual
//entries for each string you have between the commas.
entries = regexp(data, ',', 'split');
```

Comment: this outputs all the information in one column and one row, it doesnt list the strings from column 1, row 1 to row 496024?

Comment: In the sample code I put up, `entries` will be a single row.  It will be indexable 1 to how ever many strings you had in the file.

Comment: how can I output entries to however many rows are in the csv file? This is a list of attributes so I need it as a list the same as the cvs file. Not just all clumped in one row.

Comment: Well, that's the downside here.  `fread` will just read in everything as a string of characters.  So no matter how many rows you have in the csv file you'll have one really long array of `char`.  This will then just return you a long row of cells (say you have 3 rows of 100 elements) there will be 300 cells then.

Comment: each string has a . (dot) at the end, could you not manipulate regexp to put each string in a new row on this basis?

Comment: `entries = regexprep(data, '.$','split');` something like this, im too new to matlab to know how its done tho.... :S or something like `entries = textscan(fid, frmt, 'Delimiter',',');` or something arghh this is so annoying.

Comment: `A = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter', ',');`  This will just return a column of all the data that was in the file as a cell array.  If you know the number of elements (and it's a rectangular matrix) you can use reshape.  It would be like `reshape(A{1}, m, n);` where m and n are rows and columns, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like: [textread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/textread.html)

```
data = textread('data.csv', '', 'delimiter', ',', ... 
            'emptyvalue', NaN);
```

Comment: `??? Error using ==> dataread
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 1) ==>
normal.\n

Error in ==> textread at 176
[varargout{1:nlhs}]=dataread('file',varargin{:});`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me is :

```
path='C:\folder1\folder2\';
data = 'data.csv';
data = dataset('xlsfile',sprintf('%s\%s', path,data));
```

Of cource you could also do the following:

```
[data,path] = uigetfile('C:\folder1\folder2\*.csv');
data = dataset('xlsfile',sprintf('%s\%s', path,data));
```

now you will have loaded the data as dataset.
An easy way to get a column 1 for example is

```
 double(data(1))
```